# How to display the name of the product and the item the item is part of in SQL

Tags: sql, oracle, select, join, rows

I have two tables, one is called items and one is called components. The items table has the following attributes:

- Item (e.g. 1, 2, 3, 4, 5)
- Category (e.g. fruit, vegetables, meat, dairy)
- Name (e.g. Apple, Carrot, Salad Box, Pear, Banana)
- Weight (e.g. 500 grams)
- Description (e.g. a single apple)
- Price (e.g. 1.00)

And the components table has the following attributes:

- Component (e.g. 1, 2, 3, 4, 5)
- Part (which references the items table for the item primary key) (e.g. 5, 6, 1, 9, 10)
- Item (which references the items table for the item primary key) (e.g. 15, 7, 3, 2, 6)

The idea is that the items table contains individual items, such as apple, as well as a box that contains many other items, such as fruit box, and the components table is used to link what items are parts in a box, e.g. apple is part of the fruit box.

What I want to do is run a query that will display the names of the items that are components within a box, as well as the name of the box.

So far I can run the following query:

```
 select 
      *
   from
      lbs_items
      join lbs_components using (item)
Which shows the names of the different boxes, but not what items are in them. And this query:
   select 
      *
   from
      lbs_components
      , lbs_items
   where
      lbs_components.part = lbs_items.item
```

Which shows the items that are part of boxes, but not what boxes they are part of.

Anyone have any ideas that can help?

Comment: Looks like a hierarchical query. Could you do the join first (in a subquery) and use a connect by clause to get the hierarchy? https://docs.oracle.com/cd/B19306_01/server.102/b14200/queries003.htm

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As explained by James in a comment, you need a join *and* a [hierarchical query](https://docs.oracle.com/cd/B19306_01/server.102/b14200/queries003.htm) here.

Something like that:

```
select LEVEL, items.* from items left join components on items.item = components.item
start with items.name='dessert'
connect by components.part = prior items.item;
```

---

given that sample data:

```
create table items (item number(3), name varchar2(80));

insert all
  into items (item,name) values (1, 'apple')
  into items (item,name) values (2, 'pear')
  into items (item,name) values (3, 'fruit box')
  into items (item,name) values (4, 'cheese')
  into items (item,name) values (5, 'dessert')
  into items (item,name) values (6, 'fried chicken')
select * from dual
;

create table components as (select 1 item, 3 part from dual
                       union all select 2, 3 from dual
                       union all select 3, 5 from dual
                       union all select 4, 5 from dual);
```

This will produce:

```
LEVEL   ITEM    NAME
1       5       dessert
2       3       fruit box
3       1       apple
3       2       pear
2       4       cheese
```